# Can't align picture and text

Tags: html, css, position

I've been trying to do a ridiculously basic task but can't get it through.

I want to have the following structure of a simple comment

```
*image*  *name*
         *comment*
```

I can't manage to place the text to the right of the image.
Here's my current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dvir0776/xaLosyjs/

```
<div class="comment"><img src="d.jpg" style="width:13%; margin-right: 12px;">
    <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
        <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
        I would love to win the iphone 6 in black or gold or the mac or the cannon they all are great I love apple products!
    </div>
</div>
```

Any tweak to fix it will be great.

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/xaLosyjs/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `float:left` to your image and it worked. Guess this is what you are looking for.

```
<div class="comment">
    <img src="d.jpg" style="float:left;width:13%; margin-right: 12px;">
             <div style="text-align:left; font-size:8pt;">
             <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;">Chris Fanelli</h5>
             comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

first, let's get rid of your inline style and use better markup, so change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="comment">
    <img src="d.jpg" />
    <div class="textbox">
         <h5>Chris Fanelli</h5>

        <p>comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and now instead of having to write again and again and again your inline styles, you can get advantage of re-usable classes, so change your CSS like this:

```
 .comment img {
    width:13%;
    margin-right: 12px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
h5 {
    font-size:18px;
}
.textbox {
    text-align:left;
    font-size:12px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v1x9xn5c/)

Comment: would love to know the reasons of the down vote on a correct answer

Comment: Hashem, your insight is very constructive as usual